# Making a stub/wrapper for a syscall?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

I am trying to add a linux syscall for an arm architecture. So far I have added a new syscall number in the /arch/arm/include/asm/unistd.h file, added a function prototype in syscalls.h and included a parameter to call the syscall in calls.S. When I compile the kernel I am able to execute the syscall using the syscall() function. I now want the user to use a wrapper or a stub to call the function so that the user does not need to remember the syscall number. How do I achieve this at the kernel level. I tried looking into the _syscall() function but it seems to be deprecated.

Thanks.

Comment: While you are waiting for answers you might read how glibc create wrappers for syscalls. "System Call Wrappers" -- https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/SyscallWrappers

Comment: What do you mean "at the kernel level"? At the kernel level, you're done. Wrappers are part of glibc. Dig through glibc sources and find an example of a wrapper (e.g. the wrapper for `read()`) and try to do something similar for your syscall